# Why am I getting an ArgumentException on TryParse?

Tags: c#

The snippet of my code is

```
    private static void parseEquationArgs ( string [] cargs, Dictionary<int,Int64> argdic )
    {
        //  cargs:  Command-line arguments
        // argdic:  Dictionary in which to place the equation arguments

        Int64 thisval;
        for ( int k = 1, n = cargs.Length; k < n; ++k )
        {
            // TryParse reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx
            if ( Int64.TryParse(cargs[k],thisval) )
            {
```

and the Error is

The best overloaded method match for 'long.TryParse(string, out long)' has some invalid arguments. I get the same error if I use `long` instead of `Int64` above. Anyhow, the documentation says that one of the signatures is

```
public static bool TryParse(
    string s,
    out long result
)
```

and so I don't understand what's going wrong here ...

Any ideas?

Comment: Does documentation you use show sample how to use the function? The link you've provided [Int64.TryParse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  does show how to call the method - not sure why you come up with your own way of doing so. Are you expecting some other behavior by omitting `out`? Also how you are getting run-time `ArgumentException` if code can't compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error because you are not using `out` modifier. It is required, you cannot omit it. Change

```
if ( Int64.TryParse(cargs[k],thisval) )
```

to

```
if ( Int64.TryParse(cargs[k], out thisval) )
```

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought it would do an implicit cast. I come from a C++ background and in C++ you can make the parameter to a function be a reference type and then call the function with a value type.